# Connect-MsolService : Authentication Error: Unexpected authentication failure

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell, multi-factor-authentication

I'm trying to connect to azure AD using "App Passwords" as authentication MFA method through powershell script.

this is my script:

```
$username = 'user@example.com'
    $Password = ConvertTo-SecureString 'MyPassword' -AsPlainText -Force
    $creds = new-object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username, $password)
    Connect-MsolService -Credential $creds
```

But I got this error:

> Connect-MsolService : Authentication Error: Unexpected authentication failure

Comment: If you enable MFA for the user, you cannot log in with username/Password!

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue. I ran the PowerShell below:

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

Connect-MsolService
```

Comment: So if I add your line to my script, it would work?

Comment: yea it should work.
I think it is related to the deprecation of TLS1.0 and 1.1.

Comment: Sorry for taking too long to try this, but i got the same problem even after I added your line 

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put the password in the parameter, because the user logs in using **MFA**, not the **username/password**, you should let it pop up the login box and trigger MFA.

There is a [similar problem](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/office-365/how-to-connect-msol-in-powershell-using-app-password/m-p/221843) here.